# Valor máximo para srand((unsigned)time(NULL) );

Tags: c, random

Estava lendo sobre os números aleatórios não serem tão aleatórios assim e vi que uma saída era alimentar uma semente com o `srand((unsigned)time(NULL) );`

Para fazer testes gerei um vetor de 100.000 posições e o ordenei, porém o mesmo só tem até o número `32767` de aleatório, ou seja, alguns números são repetidos várias vezes.

Fiz alguma coisa errada ou o valor máximo para o `srand` é esse mesmo?

Segue o código em `C`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int vet[100000];


    int main()
    {
    int x, y, j, aux;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL) );

    for(x=1 ; x <= 100000; x++){
          vet[x]= rand();
     //   printf("Número %d: %d\n",x, vet[x]); //Tirei essa linha só pra não poluir a tela
// com os gerados aleatoriamente e depois com os ordenados
    }

    for(x=0; x<=100000; x++ ){
              for( y=x+1; y<=100000; y++ ){
                   if( vet[x] > vet[y] ){
                       aux = vet[x];
                       vet[x] = vet[y];
                       vet[y] = aux;
                   }
              }
       }
       printf("\nVetor ordenado (ou nao): \n\n");
       x=1;
       for(j=1;j<=100000;j++)
       {
                printf("Numero %d: %d\n",j, vet[x]);
                x++;
       }
}
```

Comment: Seu código está errado no acesso a arrays. Um array de 100000 elementos pode ser acessado com os índices 0  a 99999.

Comment: Fiz essa alteração, mas não adiantou. Coloquei para começar em 1 porque não queria que aparecesse "Número 0: valor x"

Comment: Poxa. Rodei meu algoritmo IDEone e rodou de boa. Tô no pc da faculdade e a hora tá errada aqui. Li que a semente é baseada na hora, quem sabe seja isso. vou tentar no meu note em casa.

Comment: A semente não parece ter relação com o problema, e sim o compilador.

Comment: Estou usando o GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: O ideone também, mas o problema não é só ser GCC, tem muita variável aí que interfere.

Comment: A correção no acesso a arrays não foi para resolver seu problema com números aleatórios, foi uma orientação geral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode obter o maior aleatório possível implementado onde está usando com `RAND_MAX`. Só implementações e plataformas muitos antigas ou ruins (Windows) são tão baixas.

Se precisar de números acima do gerado tem que criar fórmulas para chegar nesse patamar, assim como é feito para obter número dentro de um determinado limite.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CJwJnk). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qfhangmh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/RandomMax.c). (2.147.483.647).

Um exemplo de fórmula (não quer dizer que seja a melhor):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define LIMITE 1000

int myrand() {
    int r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) r = (r << 15) | (rand() & 0x7FFF);
    return r & 0xFFFFFFFF;
}

int main() {
    int vet[LIMITE];
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (int x = 0 ; x < LIMITE; x++) vet[x] = myrand();
    for (int x = 0; x < LIMITE; x++) {
        for (int y = x + 1; y < LIMITE; y++) {
            if (vet[x] > vet[y]) {
                int aux = vet[x];
                vet[x] = vet[y];
                vet[y] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nVetor ordenado (ou nao): \n\n");
    for (int x = 0; x < LIMITE; x++) printf("Numero %d: %d\n", x + 1, vet[x]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/AIy9fE). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ftcrhylz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/RandomMax2.c). (não ajuda muito, no Windows dá para ver melhor).

Comment: Substitui meu vet[x]= rand(); por vet[x]= RAND_MAX; e fiz um teste com 10 posições, mas agora todas as 10 posições geraram 32767

Comment: Ahh, rodei seu exemplo do IDEone no meu Codeblocks e o resultado foi o mesmo 32767

Comment: Eu não falei pra colocar o `RAND_MAX`, falei que pode verificar o máximo com ele. Agora sabemos que está usando uma implementação antiga/ruim. E que você terá que usar fórmulas para atingir valores maiores que o `RAND_MAX`.

Comment: Pelo jeito, no Windows (mesmo 64 bits) RAND_MAX é mesmo 32767...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074879/rand-4000000000ul-giving-only-small-values

Comment: Fechou. Estou no W7

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer nesse caso você pode chamar o rand mais de uma vez. Quando for assim, comente do sistema na pergunta tb. Um exemplo pra gerar numeros maiores seria `rand() * RAND_MAX + rand()`, ou `rand() << 15 | rand()` no caso especifico do 32767. De qq forma, teria que verificar o RAND_MAX para decidir a melhor estratégia de acordo com o ambiente.

Comment: @Bacco: seria melhor a fórmula `rand() * (RAND_MAX + 1) + rand()`

Comment: @pmg de fato, seria o correto, senão o RAND_MAX teria 1/32767 a mais de chance, e faltaria um numero na lista ainda :). Fui exemplificar rapidamente, e não cuidei bem dos detalhes.

Answer (score 0):

Os números gerados por `rand()` são **pseudo**-aleatórios, não aleatórios (afinal de contas, são gerados por um algoritmo, não tem com serem aleatórios).

Agora, esse número 32767 é suspeito, pois é o maior número inteiro positivo representado em 16 bits (em notação complemento de 2).

Aparentemente o algoritmo de geração de números pseudo-aleatórios trabalha apenas com 16 bits, no ambiente que você usou para testes.